# How to prove that $\max(\min(g,M),-M)$ is close to $f$, given $g$ is close to $f$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Prove $|\max(\min(g|_K,M),-M)-f|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in K$, if $|f-g|_K|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in K$ and $|f|\leq M$

$f$ is a function from $K$ to $R$, $g$ is a function from $R^n$ to $R$

$K$is a compact subset of $R^n$

$f,g$ continuos if necessary.

Original problem:

(b) If f is bounded by M, prove that the approximations F as in the previous part can be chosen also bounded by M. You may assume that if F, G are continuous, then min(F, G) and max(F, G) are also continuous.

Comment: Perhaps it is my own incompetence, but I find this wholly undecipherable. What is $M$? $f$? Domains, ranges? It would help a lot if you would declare your variables. It would also help if you stated what you were trying to prove.

Comment: Consider 3 cases separately: $g>|M|$, $g<-|M|$ and $|g|\le |M|$.

Comment: it does not makes sense to define g a funczion from R^n instead of K because f-g and the max-min expression ins only defined over K.

Comment: @AndresMejia Edited.

Comment: what do you mean? I never mentioned $x$

Comment: I tthink it does not make sense to pose this question for functions because all definitions are pointwise. so it is sufficient to show this for numbers g and f

Comment: @A.S. Can you be more precise? What x are you choosing?

Comment: how is subtraction being defined? What is $r-f$ for some real number $r$?

Comment: can you tell us where you found this problem?

Comment: @miracle173 edited

Comment: @miracle173 I think I get it since the max-min can be taken off in K

Comment: I already mentioned that it is sufficient to show it for numbers f and g. To show it for numbers you have to check different cases

Comment: besides that, why should g be a function from R^n intead of K. In all expressions it is restricted to K.

Answer (score 0):

Define $g^M \colon K \to \mathbf R$ by 
$$ g^M(x) := \max\Bigl(\min\bigl(g(x), M\bigr), -M \Bigr) $$
Suppose $\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\abs{f-g} < \epsilon$ on $K$ and $\abs f \le M$. Let $x \in K$, then

- If $\abs{g(x)}\le M$, then $g^M(x) = g(x)$, hence $$ \abs{g^M(x) - f(x)} = \abs{g(x) - f(x)} < \epsilon $$
- If $g(x) > M$, then $g^M(x) = M$. Note that $\abs{f(x)} \le M$, that is $f(x) \le M \le g(x)$, we have 
  $$ \abs{g^M(x) - f(x)} = \abs{M - f(x)} = M - f(x) < g(x)-f(x) = \abs{g(x) - f(x)} < \epsilon $$
- If $g(x) < -M$, then $g^M(x) = -M$. Note that $\abs{f(x)} \le M$, that is $f(x) \ge -M \ge g(x)$, we have 
  $$ \abs{g^M(x) - f(x)} = \abs{ f(x) + M} = f(x) + M < f(x)-g(x) = \abs{g(x) - f(x)} < \epsilon $$

As $x \in K$ was arbirary, we have $\abs{f-g^M} < \epsilon$ on $K$, which was to be proven.